# how to make row sum data frame in pandas?

Tags: pandas, rowsum

i have data frame as follows
and i wanna make a row sum new dataframe
and a,b,c,d column values is string.

```
      name  a         b     c      d 
      aa.   10,000  1,000 1,000  1,000
      bb.   10,000  1,000 1,000  1,000
      cc.   10,000  1,000 1,000  1,000
      dd.   10,000  1,000 1,000  1,000
      ee.   10,000  1,000 1,000  1,000
      ff.   10,000  1,000 1,000  1,000
      gg.   10,000  1,000 1,000  1,000
```

for example, new row sum dataframe should as belows

```
  sum   70,000  70,000 70,000  70,000
```

i tried using df.sumO() but got a object type. but i need 
is dataframe like sum 70,000  70,000 70,000  70,000

so i question to here. thank you in advance !

Comment: `name` is column or index? If index use `df.loc['sum'] = df.sum()`

Comment: name  is just column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum` by all columns and then set `sum` value to last value of `name` column:

```
i = len(df)
df.loc[i] = df.sum()
df.loc[i, 'name'] = 'sum'
print (df)
  name   a   b   c   d
0  aa.   1   1   1   1
1  bb.   1   0   0   1
2  cc.   3   4   4   4
3  dd.   2   2   2   2
4  ee.   1   1   1   1
5  ff.   1   1   1   1
6  gg.   1   1   1   1
7  sum  10  10  10  11
```

EDIT: If possible columns are non numeric, use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for all columns without first, get sum and add `name` value to `Series`, last assign new row:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum()
s.loc['name'] = 'sum'
df.loc[len(df)] = s

print (df)
  name   a   b   c   d
0  aa.   1   1   1   1
1  bb.   1   0   0   1
2  cc.   3   4   4   4
3  dd.   2   2   2   2
4  ee.   1   1   1   1
5  ff.   1   1   1   1
6  gg.   1   1   1   1
7  sum  10  10  10  11
```

Comment: if the a,b,c,d values is string how can i convert it to numbers and make sum ?

Comment: @jerryhan - Are values generated from file? Is possible use `df = df.read_csv(file, thousands=',')` ?